# Predicate genitive

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, possessives, of-genitive

Can anyone give me a syntactical description for this of-construction, does it imply possessiveness or the characteristic of something?

> The lunatic, the lover, and the poet, are of imagination all compact;
>
> *A Midsummer Night's Dream*

Comment: Have you done any research of your own, using  dictionary to see what the meaning of 'compact' in Tudor English might be? That is where your answer lies.  Have you looked up the word 'of'?  Possession is not the only use of 'of'.  It can also be used to indicate origin ("born of the Holy Ghost"), composition ('made of recyclable materials' or 'full of water')...

Comment: To be fair, the 'Belts, shoes and saddles are of leather all made' sentence order is also a complication here. As is the fact that the Shakespeare statement is an abstraction (one [at least] is tempted to think of 'sugar and spice, and all things nice' ... or worse). And, like the leather example, open to debate (synthetic materials).

Comment: "Of imagination" is genitive of material.

Comment: Wow, i never thought of word order; that makes sense now, thank you all.

Comment: Compact of imagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the etymology of *compact*:

> [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/compact)
>
> compact (adj.)
>
> late 14c., of substances, "closely and firmly united," from Latin compactus "concentrated," past participle of compingere "to fasten together, construct," from com "with, together" (see com-) + pangere "to fix, fasten" (from PIE root *pag- "to fasten").

Now consider the context, which is set a little later than the 14c but we may suppose *compact* still had the same meaning.

*The lunatic, the lover and the poet*
*Are of imagination all compact:*

*One sees more devils than vast hell can hold,*
*That is, the madman:*

*the lover, all as frantic,*
*Sees Helen's beauty in a brow of Egypt:*

*The poet's eye, in fine frenzy rolling,*
*Doth glance from heaven to earth, from earth to heaven;*
*And as imagination bodies forth*
*The forms of things unknown, the poet's pen*
*Turns them to shapes and gives to airy nothing*
*A local habitation and a name.*

Shakespeare thus lists three sorts of person: lover, lunatic, and poet.

The lunatic unrealistically imagines more devils than Hell could hold.

The lover imagines great beauty where there is only an eyebrow or a forehead.

The poet attributes meaning and form to nothing; he or she imagines things that are not present in the real world.

And hence the characteristics of each person are compact (constructed) of imagination. They all create imagined concepts from nothing or almost nothing. This is the meaning of the quotation.